# Get collection sort order fields

Tags: magento

Does anyone know of a clever way to read sort order array from Magento product collection? There's a protected property `_orders` in the object. I could reach it over

`$collection->getSelect()->getPart('order')`

but then I'd have to do string parsing. 
I was hoping there was a public method of some sort that would fetch sort order info from product collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a product collection with toolbar you can ask the toolbar the current sorting order:

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->getCurrentOrder()
```

Comment: it works for my current situation, but the downside of this approach is that it lists only one order, where as a collection might have two or more.. in those cases, `Reflection` might be a better solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reflection` :

```
$property = new ReflectionProperty(get_class($collection), '_orders');
$property->setAccessible(true);
$orders = $property->getValue($collection);
```

But you won't avoid some string parsing, as order values are stored in strings (`$field.' '.Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_(ASC|DESC)`)

Comment: yup I considered `Reflection` but it seemed a bit hacky. It is a solution though.